# How do you find the length of columns in a 2D array using double pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

Hello for my program I need to find the length of words stored using double char pointers to make a sort of 2D array. Whenever I try to use `strlen` or `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` it returns a massive number instead of the amount of characters that each column has stored(the size of the strings). I think that this may have something to do with null pointers but I'm not sure how I would go about fixing that if it were the case.

These are the two lines of code I am using to try and determine the sizes of the strings. The first one also forces me to restart my terminal as ctrl+c won't even stop it. The second just returns a very very large number when I print it.

```
int wordlength = sizeof(*(list+listPos))/sizeof(*(*(list+listPos)));

int wordlength = strlen(*(list+listPos));
```

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. What is `list`? What is`listPos`? What is `arr`? And note that if you have pointers, then the size of a pointer is the size of the pointer itself, not what it points to.

Answer (score 0):

Here you got a sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void) {
  char **arr;
  arr=malloc(2*sizeof(char*));
  *arr=malloc(20*sizeof(char));
  strcpy(*arr,"Hello World");
  int len=strlen((*arr+0));
  printf("%s %d",*arr,len); //output Hello World 11
  return 0;
}
```

When you wrote it like this:

```
strlen(*(list+listPos));
```

You tried to acces value from array of strings and just adress from string not its value.

Comment: `*arr = ...` directly followed by `*arr = ...` is making the first assignment moot. You probably want `strcpy` instead of the second assignment.

Comment: Also please don't use pointer arithmetic for what is essentially arrays. Instead of `*arr` use `arr[0]`. And `*arr+0` doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: Unfortunately I get used to it coz at my Uni they excluded [ ] from codes when we gives our assignments and I needed to use only pointers arithmetics even when we got ****arr :')

Comment: That's academics for you... :) Using "array" like syntax with `[]` generally makes the code easier to read and understand, and therefore also to maintain.